# Does the receiver of a large international server to server transmission have to pay Cost Of Transaction fees in advance

Tags: wire-transfer

I've received documents for a large international server to server transmission. Do I present the documents to a bank?  The Provider wants to remain confidential but did provide a passport photo and other information.  As Receiver, do I have to pay Cost Of Transaction Fees in advance?  How do I know if this is legitimate?

Someone I know claimed to recommend my business to a group of investors. I am very suspicious that it's a scam. The documents came to me via an email account I provided. What seems odd is that I was told not to show the documents to a bank. I've also been told that I would have to pay COT in advance.

Comment: Can you give us some context? Who gave you these documents and why? How do you know this person? What have they asked you to do? This certainly sounds like a scam but I feel like we are missing part of the story.

Comment: Someone I know claimed to recommend my business to a group of investors.  I am very suspicious that it's a scam.  The documents came to me via an email account I provided.  What seems odd is that I was told not to show the documents to a bank. I've also been told that I would have to pay COT in advance.

Comment: What is a "server to server transmission", and why do you have to pay Cost Of Transaction Fees?

Comment: What do the documents say?

Comment: The answer is a simple NO.  And this is clearly an advanced-fee scam.

Answer (score 4):

This is pegging the scam-o-meter *hard*.  This is going to go one of several ways.

### There are up-front fees you must pay in advance.

You'll pay them.  And we're almost there, but oh wait, there'll be *another* fee you need to pay. And another.   And another.  They will game your expectations until you've sunk quite a lot in fees.

The promised money never existed, of course.  When you finally say "Enough!" They disappear, and you find this all happened informally, and you have no bona-fide contact info to give police.

Genuine lenders and investors  do not confine themselves to email, chat and things they can do behind a VPN from an Internet cafe in Romania.  *The biggest worry in the room should be **theirs**, worrying that you're the real deal, competent, and have a workable business model. They should be extensively vetting you.*

Yes, I know you watch "Shark Tank" and you see complete strangers walk on stage going "Hi, I'm Joe Blow, I have a gadget that clips onto phones to make them easier to hold", and just like that the sharks are bidding. **That is theater. Actually, the investors' staff has already spent weeks or months vetting** these contestants, otherwise they would never be invited to set foot on that stage.  The laborious vetting is not ever shown, because it would be boring TV.

So if they're not vetting you to death, they're fake.

### The money appears to arrive, but then evaporates

This scam works like this.

1. The transaction appears to have gone through.  Money shows up in tour account, looks good.
2. You send some of the money back - typically as a money transfer back to them, Bitcoin, gift cards and the like; but potentially also as consumer products or other items of value, or even services.  If they say "deduct your salary from this" that's always a scam.
3. The transaction then turns out to be no good.  The money that appeared in your account now disappears. They used to use defective cashier's checks designed would pinball  all over the world banking system for weeks before finally being ruled no good.  However they may have new ways of creating that delayed effect.  It may also be a real person's money and his bank account was hacked, and he now discovered this and "clawed back" the money.
4. Your bank account is now overdrawn by the amount you sent back.  You owe this to the bank.

### Or it might be real money laundering

It might actually be worse if the money is real.  The civilized governments of the world try to contain terrorism and other serious crime by a) tracking money movements and b) making it difficult to flow money in/out of certain crime or terror groups or rogue states.

So these criminals do extreme, weird things to move money.  They often enroll innocent citizens into committing financial crimes for them, exploiting their unawareness of what financial crime is.

When the authorities follow the money, they find YOU.

The upshot is

### If it's weird, and involves money, *avoid at all costs*.

Desperation and optimism are what they prey on.